# What does the : symbol mean in React createClass() method?

Tags: reactjs

Here's some sample code from ReactKungfu:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

What does the `:` in `render: function()` signify? I haven't seen this explained in vanilla JS tutorials I have done, although I believe it signifies "[something]  in [this other list/range] in Java

Comment: It's just a normal object. The opening curly brace is at the end of the previous line.

Comment: @JJJ thanks! I kind of missed the JSON structure when I was staring at this for 15 mins

Comment: That happens, although [it's not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181).

Comment: @JJJ fair point -- so reading from your link, is it accurate to say this `{render: ... }` is a JavaScript object literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly brackets you put around the data passed into the function represent a JS object. `render` is simply a member variable of that object, so the `:` is to define that variable as the function after it.

It's basically equivalent to `let render = function() { ... }` outside of an object.